# Help showing $\frac{\mathbf{C}[x]}{(x-1, x-2)} \cong \mathbf{C}^2$ (EDIT: FALSE)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My algebra professor told us as an exercise that

$$\frac{\mathbf{C}[x]}{(x-1, x-2)} \cong \mathbf{C}^2. $$

I have been having trouble showing this is true.

Can anyone help me out?  Thanks

Comment: As written this is false. The ideal you are quotienting by contains $1$ so is the whole ring. So the quotient is trivial.

Comment: Oh I see...thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that your professor meant $\mathbb C[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle$?

Comment: Oh, now that I look at it, that's what is written...whoops

Comment: I just map to $\mathbf{C}^2$ evaluating at $1$ in the first coordinate and at $2$ in the second coordinate, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathmo123 points out in the comments, $\Bbb C[x]/(x-1,x-2)\cong 0$, since $1 = (x-1) - (x - 2)\in (x - 1, x - 2)$, and hence you're looking at the quotient of $\Bbb C[x]$ by itself. To evaluate $\Bbb C[x]/((x - 1)(x - 2))$, try using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings).